# Is my query which will be executed correct?

Tags: mysql

> Author(AuthorID, AuthorName, Address, TelephoneNo, PublisherCode)
>
> Book (BookID, Name, ReleaseDate, Price, AuthorID)
>
> Publisher(PublisherID, Name, Address, AuthorID)
>
> A book can only have one Author.
>
> A book can only belong to one Publisher.
>
> Write a query to pick out and show all the details of Authors who
>   released books last year.

This is the mysql query I have answered with, I would like to know if it is correct or is there is a better way of writing it?

```
SELECT Author.*,  b.ReleaseDate
FROM Author a JOIN Book b ON a.AuthorID = b.AuthorID
WHERE b.ReleaseDate >= ‘2018-01-01’ AND  b.ReleaseDate <= ‘2018-12-31’
```

Comment: It looks fine other than `1018` should be `2018`, and you can write the `WHERE` clause using `BETWEEN`: `WHERE b.ReleaseDate BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'`

Comment: well, '1018-01-01' seems not the last year

Comment: @ Nick: Thanks :)

Comment: Hmm, that qould show authors, who have release _n_ books in 2018 _n_ times. E.g. if an author has released two books, they're listed twice in your result. Is that intended?

Comment: The `‘` and `’` should be `'`, And instead of `b.ReleaseDate <= '2018-12-31'` better use `b.ReleaseDate < '2019-01-01'` that also works if there's an hour (minute, second) portion not being zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get ride off innecesary query text you could use the year function.

Example:

```
SELECT Author.*,  b.ReleaseDate FROM Author a JOIN Book b ON a.AuthorID = b.AuthorID WHERE year(b.ReleaseDate) = ‘2018’
```